# read text from dropdownlist & writ its corresponding id in DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Please help me !!!  when I select a Client in DropDownListe I want that its corresponding ID will be written in my table (cascad) in the database and not the name . Here is my code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into cascad(Client ) values('" + ddlClients.SelectedItem + "')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        Response.Redirect("Cascad.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question _exactly_?

Comment: use ``ddlClients.SelectedValue``

Comment: ddlClients.SelectedIndex does not work.

Comment: when I select an item from the dropdownlist wich is related to a table in the data base, I wouldn't return in the cascad table the text selected in the dropdownlist but its ID

Comment: Thanks friends I had to use SelsectedValue :)

Answer (score -1):

First make sure that you've created the DDL so that it has both the ClientID and the ClientText. You can do that by specifying both the DataValueField and DataTextField before you databind the ddl.

```
    ddlClients.DataValueField = "ClientID";
    ddlClients.DataTextField  = "EnterYourClientTextColNameHere";
```

Then when you're getting the value back from the ddl, use the SelectedValue property which will contain the ClientID associated with the ddl selection.  Like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //use a sqlparameter to avoid the possibility of sql injection
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("p1", ddlClients.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into cascad(Client) values(@p1)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Cascad.aspx");
    }
```

Note that i swapped in a sqlparameter rather than concatenating the ddls value directly into the sql statement so as to avoid the possibility of sql injection.